# .htacces & RewriteRule: all links are broken now (after RewriteRule was applied for modifying URL)

Tags: mod-rewrite, path, hyperlink, relative-path

After `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]` was applied, now you can type `mysite.com/aboutus/` as well as `mysite.com/?p=aboutus`. Now another problem appeared:
If you type `mysite.com/aboutus/`, then the page and pictures load fine, but links on the page `mysite.com/aboutus/` will look like: `mysite.com/aboutus/index.php?p=link1` instead of `mysite.com/index.php?p=link1`  (also `mysite.com/link1` would be even better!).
How to solve this question? There are too many links to replace them manually.

P.S. Every link looks like `<a href="?p=link1" > click here </a>` and NOT like `http://mysite.com?p=link1`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another RewriteRule:

```
^(/[^/]+/index\.php\?p=([.]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

This will make your links valid but redundant. You will still have links like `http://mysite.com/path_1/index.php?p=link1` and `http://mysite.com/path_2/index.php?p=link1` in your pages.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess is not in any way responsible for how your software links to things, it rewrites incoming urls from the user, not your HTML files. If the links are made relative to the path, then you end up with the problem you're describing.

If you're the author of the software you don't really have any choice but to replace the links. If you're using some other software it might have an option for search engine friendly urls.